# Java parked thread

Tags: java, multithreading

What is the difference between a parked thread and a waiting thread in java ? I've a jboss core dump and analysing it is showing a lot of parked threads.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Look at [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.html#park%28%29) the `park()` method:

> Disables the current thread for thread scheduling purposes unless the
>   permit is available. If the permit is available then it is consumed
>   and the call returns immediately; otherwise the current thread becomes
>   disabled for thread scheduling purposes and lies dormant until one of
>   three things happens:
>
> Some other thread invokes unpark with the current thread as the
>   target; or Some other thread interrupts the current thread; or The
>   call spuriously (that is, for no reason) returns. This method does not
>   report which of these caused the method to return. Callers should
>   re-check the conditions which caused the thread to park in the first
>   place. Callers may also determine, for example, the interrupt status
>   of the thread upon return.

So a parked thread is a thread blocked using `LockSupport.park()`.

Comment: While being the accepted answer, this answer provides little to no intuition into the usefulness of `park` versus other options

Answer (score 9):

Both park() and wait() will result in a disabled thread. Making a disabled thread active again depends on how it was disabled.

A thread that has been disabled by calling [`LockSupport.park()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.html#park%28%29) will remain disabled until:

- some other thread calls [`unpark()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.html#unpark(java.lang.Thread)), or
- some other thread calls [`interrupt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()), or
- "the call spuriously (that is, for no reason) returns"

A thread that has been disabled by calling Object's [wait()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()) – which is equivalent to calling [`wait(0)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait(long)) – will remain disabled until:

- some other thread calls [`notify()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify()) or [`notifyAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notifyAll()), or
- some other thread calls [`interrupt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()) on the disabled thread

Answer (score 5):

In Java, a **parked** thread by calling `LockSupport.park()` method is a waiting thread ( in the `Thread.state.WAITING` ).

See the Java Doc for  [Thread.state.WAITING](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html#WAITING).

There are 3 ways to cause a thread to be in the WAITING status:

1. Object.wait with no timeout
2. Thread.join with no timeout
3. LockSupport.park

A thread in the waiting state is waiting for another thread to perform a particular action.

For example, a thread that has called Object.wait() on an object is waiting for another thread to call Object.notify() or Object.notifyAll() on that object. A thread that has called Thread.join() is waiting for a specified thread to terminate.

Comment: this might be helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497793/understanding-java-lang-thread-state-waiting-parking

Answer (score 2):

**Parking** means suspending execution until permit is available. **Permit** means a permission to continue execution.
A thread can suspend its execution until permit is available. When permit is available, the parked thread consumes it and exits a **park() method**.

Answer (score -2):

LockSupport - class takes facility basic thread blocking primitives for creating locks and other synchronization classes.

Method park() disables the current thread for thread scheduling purposes unless the permit is available.

unpark(Thread thread) makes available the permit for the given thread, if it was not already available.

Use it like:
    finally {
        LockSupport.unpark(thread);
      }