# Future.get is blocking?

Tags: android, executorservice

With reference to the following code.

```
for (Future<Long> future : list) {
            try {
                sum += future.get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Now when i call future.get will this be blocking call? So if i am executing this on the Main Thread of and android application will this cause an ANR exception ? I notice the Interrupted exception is also thrown, so does this mean their is a sleep called on the thread in the get function ?

Answer (score 7):

1. Yes, documentation of `Future.get()` says:

   > Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.

   so, it will block until results of computation are available, or the computation was interrupted (cancelled or resulting in exception).
2. It *may* cause ANR if your computations take long time to finish.
3. Again, from documentation of `Future.get()`:

   > @throws InterruptedException if the current thread was interrupted while waiting

   Now, since you call `Future.get()` from main thread, I suspect that it is the Android system which interrupts your main thread in an attempt to make it responsive again. But it may also be caused by another thread of your application - it's hard to tell, since you haven't specified what your application does, what threads does it create, when, do you use ExecutorService (and if so, which implementation), and so on.
4. No, `FutureTask.get()` (which I believe is the implementation of `Future` you're using) does not call `Thread.sleep()`. Instead, putting the thread in waiting mode is done via *thread parking* which causes it to not be scheduled for execution until a signal is given. This may cause in ANR error if done in the main thread. For details of `parking` mechanism consider reading documentation and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7497793/1820695)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check if future "is done" by calling future.isDone(). Code example:

```
String result = "";

if (myFuture.isDone()) result = (String) myFuture.get();
```

You will probably want to check it in an endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

Beware of deadlock with `future.get()`. If both the `MainThread`, that call `future.get()`, and the `WorkerThread` is synchronized (on the same object) then you get a deadlock.