# Parking threads in service

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, parking

I'm experimenting with threads parking and decided to build some sort of service. Here is how it looks like:

```
public class TestService {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestService.class); // logback I think this logger causes some troubles

    private final CountDownLatch stopLatch;
    private final Object parkBlocker = new Object();
    private volatile boolean stopped;
    private final Thread[] workers;

    public TestService(int parallelizm) {
        stopLatch = new CountDownLatch(parallelizm);
        workers = new Thread[parallelizm];
        for (int i = 0; i < parallelizm; i++) {
            workers[i] = new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    while (!stopped) {
                        logger.debug("Parking " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        LockSupport.park(parkBlocker);
                        logger.debug(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " unparked");
                    }
                } finally {
                    stopLatch.countDown();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void start() {
        Arrays.stream(workers).forEach(t -> {
            t.start();
            logger.debug(t.getName() + " started");
        });
    }

    public boolean stop(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
        boolean stoppedSuccefully = false;
        this.stopped = true;
        unparkWorkers();
        if (stopLatch.await(timeout, unit)) {
            stoppedSuccefully = true;
        }
        return stoppedSuccefully;
    }

    private void unparkWorkers() {
        Arrays.stream(workers).forEach(w -> {
            LockSupport.unpark(w);
            logger.debug("Un-park call is done on " + w.getName());
        });
    }
}
```

The issue I faced with was that if I then test this service as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) = {
  while(true) {
    TestService service = new TestService(2);
    service.start();
    if (!service.stop(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
      throw new RuntimeException();
  }
}
```

I sometimes got the following behavior:

```
14:58:55.226 [main] DEBUG com.pack.age.TestService - Thread-648 started
14:58:55.227 [Thread-648] DEBUG com.pack.age.TestService - Parking Thread-648
14:58:55.227 [main] DEBUG com.pack.age.TestService - Thread-649 started
14:58:55.227 [main] DEBUG com.pack.age.TestService - Un-park call is done on Thread-648
14:58:55.227 [Thread-648] DEBUG com.pack.age.TestService - Thread-648 unparked
14:58:55.227 [main] DEBUG com.pack.age.TestService - Un-park call is done on Thread-649
14:58:55.227 [Thread-649] DEBUG com.pack.age.TestService - Parking Thread-649
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException
    at com.pack.age.Test$.main(Test.scala:12)
    at com.pack.age.Test.main(Test.scala)
```

The thread is hanging out on parking:

```
"Thread-649" #659 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007efe4433f000 nid=0x7691 waiting on condition [0x00007efe211c8000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0000000720739a68> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at com.pack.age.TestService.lambda$new$0(TestService.java:27)
    at com.pack.age.TestService$$Lambda$1/1327763628.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I don't see any race in park-unpark in the service. Moreover if the `unpark` is called before `park`, the `park` is guaranteed no to block (that's what javadocs say).

Maybe I misuse `LockSupport::park`. Can you suggest any fix?

Comment: I don't seem to get that exception; I've been running your code for 3 minutes now...

Comment: @daniu Did you use log4j/logback?

Comment: no, actually, `java.util.logging` (don't have log4j here). Maybe it really is the problem (although I don't see how).

Comment: @daniu Actually I tried first to just `System.out.println` all messages and the code worked fine. After switching to log4j/logback I started fcing this issue.

Comment: @daniu Seems this is because logback. It uses `ReentrantLock` for synchronization which in turn uses parks thread for waiting (via `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer`). So `LockSupport::park` seems not safe to use with sort of "alien" code which can park/unpark threads itself.

Comment: That is weird, and if it's due to the use `ReentrantLock`, it's an issue with that rather than logback (which only introduces the problem in your case) - so it's an actual JDK issue. After all, you might be using `ReentrantLock` in other (non-"alien") code parts and cause the same behavior.

Comment: @daniu The thing what's confusing me is that `unpark` does not accept a `blocker` object. Just a thread.

Comment: Well you wouldn't be able to `unpark()` with a blocker object if you're using the same one (as you do). But in general I agree that `unpark()` accepts `Thread`, especially since the preferred Java concurrency handling uses `ExecutorService`s and does not involve the direct use of `Thread` itself at all anymore. That's probably also the way to solve your problem.

Comment: @daniu I can imagine the scenarion when we unpark a worker in order to gain permit. Then this worker is blocking on `ReentrantLock` so the permit is lost. And next time we park the thread it will be parked (permit was lost in `ReentrantLock`). Is it correct?

Comment: @daniu Reproduced the behavior replacing logback calls with `lock.lock(); long l = 0; while(l++ < 100000000L){} lock.unlock();`

Comment: The `LockSupport` javadoc does state "Basic thread blocking primitives for creating locks and other synchronization classes". I guess the lesson is "don't use it along with locks" (and rather stay on the same synchronization level).

Comment: @daniu Sounds reasonable, thanks.

Comment: @daniu it's a [bit simpler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61149733/1059372), I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with logger, though it's usage brings the problem to the surface. You have a race condition, as simple as that. Before explaining that race condition you need to understand a few things from `LockSupport::unpark` documentation first:

> Makes available the permit for the given thread, if it was not already available.  If the thread was blocked on park then it will unblock.  **Otherwise, its next call to park is guaranteed not to block.**

The first point is explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497793/understanding-java-lang-thread-state-waiting-parking/51788005#51788005). The short version is : if you have a `thread` that has already been started, but *has not yet* called `park`, and within this period of time (between the `start` of the thread and `park`), some other thread calls `unpark` on the first one : that thread will not park, at all. The permit will be available immediately. May be this little drawing will make it more clear:

```
(ThreadA)  start ------------------ park --------- ....

(ThreadB)  start ----- unpark -----
```

Notice how `ThreadB` calls `unpark(ThreadA)` between the period where `ThreadA` has called `start` and `park`. As such, when `ThreadA` reaches `park`: **it is guaranteed not to block**, exactly like the documentation says.

The second point from the same documentation is:

> This operation is not guaranteed to have any effect at all if the given thread has not been started.

Let's see that via a drawing:

```
Thread B calls unpark(ThreadA) --- Thread A starts --- Thread A calls park
```

After `ThreadA` calls `park`, it will hang forever, since `ThreadB` never calls `unpark` on it again. Notice that the call to `unpark` was made *before* `ThreadA` has started (unlike the previous example).

And this is exactly what happens in your case:

`LockSupport.unpark(w);` (from `unparkWorkers`) is called *before*  `t.start();` from `public void start(){...}`. In simpler words - your code calls `unpark` on both `workers` *before* they even start, as such when they ultimately reach `park` - they are stuck, no one is able to `unpark` them. The fact that you see this with a `logger` and not with `System::out` has most probably to do with the face that when you `println` - there is a `synchronized` method under the hood.

---

As a matter of fact, `LockSupport` offers exactly the semantics needed to prove this. For this we need (for simplicity : `SOProblem service = new SOProblem(1);`)

```
static class ParkBlocker {

    private volatile int x;

    public ParkBlocker(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
}
```

And now we need to insert this in proper methods. First flag that fact that we have called `unpark`:

```
private void unparkWorkers() {
    Arrays.stream(workers).forEach(w -> {
        LockSupport.unpark(w);
        logger.debug("Un-park call is done on " + w.getName());
    });
    /*
     * add "1" to whatever there is already in pb.x, meaning
     * we have done unparking _also_
     */
    int y = pb.x;
    y = y + 1;
    pb.x = y;
}
```

Then reset the flag after a cycle has ended:

```
public boolean stop(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
    boolean stoppedSuccefully = false;
    stopped = true;
    unparkWorkers();
    if (stopLatch.await(timeout, unit)) {
        stoppedSuccefully = true;
        // reset the flag
        pb.x = 0;
    }
    return stoppedSuccefully;
}
```

Then change the constructor to flag that the thread has started:

```
  .....
  while (!stopped) {
       logger.debug("Parking " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
       // flag the fact that thread has started. add "2", meaning
       // thread has started
       int y = pb.x;
       y = y + 2;
       pb.x = y;
       LockSupport.park(pb);
       logger.debug(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " unparked");
  }
```

Then, when your thread freezes you need to inspect the flag:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    while (true) {
        SOProblem service = new SOProblem(1); // <-- notice a single worker, for simplicity
        service.start();
        if (!service.stop(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
            service.debug();
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }
}
```

where `debug` method is:

```
public void debug() {
    Arrays.stream(workers)
          .forEach(x -> {
              ParkBlocker pb = (ParkBlocker) LockSupport.getBlocker(x);
              if (pb != null) {
                  System.out.println("x = " + pb.getX());
              }
          });
}
```

When the issue re-produces, you have called `unpark` *before* you called `park`, that happens when `x = 3` as the output.