# Understanding CompletableFuture simple implementation

Tags: java, multithreading, completable-future

Consider the following code taken from [this article](https://medium.com/@sergeykuptsov/how-it-works-in-java-completablefuture-3031dbbca66d). It implements something similar to a CompletableFuture for learning purposes.

Here's the `get()` function of `WaitingFuture`:

```
@Override
public V get() throws ExecutionException {
    this.thread = Thread.currentThread();
    LockSupport.park(this);

    if (throwable != null) {
        throw new ExecutionException(throwable);
    }

    return result;
}
```

And here's the `run()` function of `RunnableWaitingFuture`:

```
@Override
    public void run() {
            try {
                waitingFuture.result = userFunction.get();
            } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                waitingFuture.throwable = throwable;
            } finally {
                waitingFuture.finished = true;
                LockSupport.unpark(waitingFuture.thread);
            }
        }
    }
```

**The Question:**
It seems to me that if `run()` will finish before `get()` is even called then `LockSupport.park(this);` will be called *after* `LockSupport.unpark(waitingFuture.thread)`, leaving the thread parking forever.

Is that true?

Comment: [The documentation for unpark](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.html#unpark(java.lang.Thread)) says:  “If the thread was blocked on park then it will unblock. Otherwise, its next call to park is guaranteed not to block.”  So the only question is what the value of `waitingFuture.thread` is at the time `unpark` is called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`park()`/`unpark()` is different to `wait`/`notify`, as the signal won’t be lost if `unpark` has been called before `park()`.

However, it’s still only a single bit that doesn’t count how often `unpark` has been called, so it’s still wrong to assume that all calls will be perfectly paired.

Further, `park` will silently return on interrupts and is even allowed to return *spuriously*, which means for no reason.

In other words, even returning from `park()` doesn’t guaranty that the condition has been fulfilled. Just like with the other notification mechanisms, there is no way around using it in a loop.

The cited code is even worse, as it has another race condition regarding the `thread` variable. There is no guaranty that it has been written at the point where the other thread reads it for notifying it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the first paragraph. It's like your'e saying the `unpark()` call presumably will cancel the `park()` call even though it happened before?

Comment: @yaseco [exactly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50370522/parking-threads-in-service/61149733#61149733)

Comment: this spurious failures sort of sucks! I don't know the inner implementation or the reason that this might happen, but I can only assume that it is the same as spurious failures in `AtomicXXX::weakXXX` or the like. In those method that has to do with weak memory model platforms, where a "dirty" cache line might trigger a spurious failure.  Do you happen to know what is going on here? I know this is too much to ask, I am just wondering. thank you.

Comment: @Eugene I don’t see any reason to be annoyed. The other aspects do already lead to the requirement to use the construct in a pre-test loop. But when you do a pre-test, it’s possible to skip a `park` when you notice that the condition is fulfilled whereas a corresponding `unpark` has been performed already. Then, the next `park` will return immediately without the condition being fulfilled. Since you have to deal with it anyway (and the pre-test loop does deal with it), the actual spurious wakeup create no additional obstacle. But I remember someone mentioning the pthread lib as a reason.

Answer (score 2):

yes.

```
LockSupport.park(this);
```

should be replaced with something like

```
while (!waitingFuture.finished) {
    LockSupport.park(this);
}
```

Generally, LockSupport.park is too low a feature, and `Object::wait` or `Condition::await` should be used instead for reliability.

Comment: The issues of the question would also arise with `Object::wait` and `Condition::await`, i.e. they must be called in a loop with a pre-test. But, of course, they are preferable, as even if the code of the article was not broken, this usage allowed at most one thread calling `get`. Trying to implement support for multiple threads using `LockSupport` would boil down to reimplementing the existing `Lock`.