# Monitoring queue of ExecutionContextExecutor "scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global"

Tags: scala, reactive-programming

Is there any way to monitor the task queue of `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global`?  ie., see the number of tasks waiting for a thread to be released?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDK comes along with `jconsole` and `jmc`. You can use them to see thread usage. You can see,

- Thread state,
- blocked count
- thread allocated bytes etc

scala implicit threads name start with `scala-execution-context-global-n`.

`jmc` screenshot:

[image: jmc screenshot]

Related: [what is the best way to get the number of futures running in background in an execution context?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52691394/432903)

Comment: Thanks, lead me to the solution. I used jstack -l which needs no front end and the actual naming of the threads is "ForkJoinPool-x-worker-y"

Comment: The question was about tasks - i.e. Futures.
How does information about threads help count the number of pending tasks?