# why got different number of threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, java-threads

Part of my scala program:

```
import java.util.concurrent.{ExecutorService, Executors, TimeUnit}

val genericExecutorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool()

val scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(4)

val scheduledExecutorService1 = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1)

val scheduledExecutorService2 = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1)
```

I counted the number of threads from the log file, and the number is 120. Part of log file:

```
2018-10-18 00:00:00,421 INFO  [pool-7-thread-32] xxx
```

Count the thread in log file:

```
$ grep -r "thread" xxx.log | grep -Po '(?<=(\[)).*(?=\])' | sort | uniq -c | wc -l
120
```

I counted the threads of java by

```
$ cat /proc/2966/status | grep Threads
Threads:    1524
$ ps -eLF| grep -c java
1525
$ ps -L -o pid= -p 2966 | wc -l
1524
```

Why `1525` and `120` so different? Any hints welcomed.
Thanks.

Comment: You are only showing logs from that particular pool?  That doesn't show other threads in your problem I suspect.  kill -quit will show you the stack traces of all threads.  Jconsole also shows the threads.

Answer (score 1):

You can use better tool to analyse the threads in JVM application instead of relying on logging. There are visual tools like `jmc` and `jconsole`. There is [`jstack`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jstack) if you on PROD machine where visual tools may not be available.

**If I've following JVM application,**

```
object Testing {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    import java.util.concurrent.{ExecutorService, Executors, TimeUnit}

    val genericExecutorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool()

    val scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(4)

    val scheduledExecutorService1 = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1)

    val scheduledExecutorService2 = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1)

    genericExecutorService.execute(() => {
      println("0")
    })

    scheduledExecutorService.execute(() => {
      println("1")
    })

    scheduledExecutorService1.execute(() => {
      println("2")
    })

    scheduledExecutorService2.execute(() => {
      println("3")
    })
  }

}
```

**I can get the threads using `jstack`** using the `proccessId` of that application,

```
$ jstack 68209 | grep thread
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.151-b12 mixed mode):
"pool-4-thread-1" #14 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007ff1b812a800 nid=0xa503 waiting on condition [0x000070000c305000]
"pool-3-thread-1" #13 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007ff1b812a000 nid=0xa703 waiting on condition [0x000070000c202000]
"pool-2-thread-1" #12 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007ff1b80f9000 nid=0xa903 waiting on condition [0x000070000c0ff000]
"pool-1-thread-1" #11 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007ff1b9869800 nid=0x5803 waiting on condition [0x000070000bffc000]
"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007ff1b9802800 nid=0x1c07 runnable 
"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007ff1b9001000 nid=0x1d03 runnable 
"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007ff1ba804800 nid=0x2b03 runnable 
"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007ff1ba805000 nid=0x5303 runnable 
"GC task thread#4 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007ff1ba805800 nid=0x5103 runnable 
"GC task thread#5 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007ff1b8810800 nid=0x2c03 runnable 
"GC task thread#6 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007ff1b981e800 nid=0x4e03 runnable 
"GC task thread#7 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007ff1b981f000 nid=0x4c03 runnable
```

you can simply do `jstack pid` as well but that gives whole dump of a thread including thread_state and all.

**Using `jmc` visual tool,**

[image: jmc]

Might be helpful:
[Monitoring queue of ExecutionContextExecutor “scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52759596/432903)